# How can I draw an empty set? Please see the content

Tags: technical-drawing

I am a new latex user. How can i use package {venndiagram} to draw a picture below? (No shading). Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (0.6) node[below=7mm]{$A$};
\draw (2,0) circle (0.6) node[below=7mm]{$B$};
\draw (3,-1.5) rectangle (-1,1) node[above left]{$\Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Please consider looking at section 2 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf).

Comment: Thank you all! zyy: I checked the section 2 of the documentation, but I think doesn't contain empty thing like my example. If you could point out where exactly it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Section 1 of the [`venndiagram` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf). In particular, the `radius` and `overlap` key-value options, and the `\setpostvennhook` command with its description paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
This:

\begin{venndiagram2sets}[overlap=-0.5cm,radius=0.8cm]
\node at ([shift={(-0.2cm,0.2cm)}] venn top left) {$\Omega$};
\end{venndiagram2sets}

Or this:

\begin{venndiagram2sets}[overlap=-0.5cm,radius=0.8cm,labelA={},labelB={}]
\node at ([shift={(-0.2cm,0.2cm)}] venn top left) {$\Omega$};
\setpostvennhook{
  \node[below] at ([shift={(-0.3cm,-1.4cm)}] labelA) {$A$};
  \node[below] at ([shift={(0.3cm,-1.4cm)}] labelB) {$B$};
}
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image: Venn]

Comment: @Liang You are welcome! If this answers you question, you may accept it by clicking the check mark.